# Spectral gap of the generator of a contraction semi-group

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, semigroup-of-operators

Let $(P_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be a strongly continuous contraction semi-group (not necessarily self-adjoint) of operators with $P_0=I$ defined on a Hilbert Space $(H,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$). Suppose $(A,D(A))$ is the generator of this semi-group. Assume that the operator $-A$ admits spectral gap, i.e, there exists $\lambda >0$ such that $\Re(\alpha)\ge\lambda$ for all $\alpha\in\sigma(-A)$, where $\sigma(-A)$ denotes the spectrum of $-A$. Is it true that $|\langle -Af,f\rangle|\ge\lambda\|f\|^2$ for all $f\in D(A)$?

Comment: Do you mean $\Re\langle -Af,f\rangle\geq \lambda\lVert f\rVert^2$?

Comment: I have edited my post. In such case $\langle Af,f\rangle$ is always real.

Comment: This is not correct. What you calculated is not the derivative of $\lVert P_t f\rVert^2$ (which would be real-valued in any case, whether $(P_t)$ is a contraction semigroup or not). A simple counterexample is given by the semigroup generated by a multiplication operator with spectrum (=essential image of the multiplying function) contained in the half-plane $\{z\colon\Re z\leq -\lambda\}$.

Comment: My bad! but isn't it the derivative at $t=0$?

Comment: No, the derivative at $t=0$ is $\langle Af,f\rangle+\langle f,Af\rangle=2\Re \langle Af,f\rangle$, which is of course real.

Comment: Thanks @MaoWao. I have edited it now. Actually for the original problem, I had a $L^2$ space and $f$ was a real valued function. Thanks for your correction. :-)